# C++ directory tree data into vector

Tags: c++, winapi, tree, filesystems, tree-traversal

Can I use Windows API `FindFirstFile` + `FindNextFile` to traverse the specified directory and all its sub directory and store all the directory name and file name on struct like this

```
typedef struct node_t
{
    vector <wstring *> val;
    vector <node_t *> subnodes;
    node_t* parent;
}*pnode, node;
```

`val` means file names on specified directory. `subnodes` means sub directory on specified directory. `parent` means the pointer point to parent node.

As this is very a tiny project I am building. I don't want to use the third-party library if not necessary.

**EDIT**

Here is my code. the result `nd` global vector variable's hierarchy result is not like my directory structure. Can you please point out the uncorrect code ?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct node_t
{
    vector <wstring> val;
    vector <node_t *> subnodes;
    node_t* parent;
}*pnode, node;

node* nd;
pnode ndparent = NULL;


void log(LPCTSTR lpRecordStr, ...)
{
    TCHAR       tszLogFile[MAX_PATH]        = {0};
    TCHAR       pInfo[1024]                 = {0};
    HRESULT     hr                          = S_FALSE;
    TCHAR       szProgramDataPath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    BOOL        bExists                     = TRUE;
    do 
    {

        SYSTEMTIME LocalTime ;
        GetLocalTime(&LocalTime);

        _stprintf_s(pInfo,_T("[test] [%04d-%02d-%02d,%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d]"),
            LocalTime.wYear,
            LocalTime.wMonth,
            LocalTime.wDay,
            LocalTime.wHour, 
            LocalTime.wMinute,
            LocalTime.wSecond,
            LocalTime.wMilliseconds
            );

        va_list argList;
        va_start(argList, lpRecordStr);
        _vsntprintf_s(pInfo + _tcslen(pInfo) , 1024 - _tcslen(pInfo) - 1 , 1024, lpRecordStr, argList);
        va_end(argList);

        _tcscat_s(pInfo , _T("\n"));
        OutputDebugString(pInfo);


    } while (FALSE);


}

VOID SearchFile(TCHAR *Path, pnode pnd)
{
    HANDLE                  hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA         wfd;
    TCHAR                   tszPathTemp[512]        =   {0};
    TCHAR                   tszParam[512]       =   {0};

    ZeroMemory(&wfd,sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));
    memset(tszPathTemp,0,sizeof(tszPathTemp));
    _stprintf_s(tszPathTemp, MAX_PATH, _T("%s\\*.*"),Path);
    hFind=FindFirstFile(tszPathTemp,&wfd);

    if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE==hFind)
    {
        return;
    }
    do
    {
        if(_tcscmp(wfd.cFileName,_T("."))==0|| _tcscmp(wfd.cFileName,_T(".."))==0 )
        {
            continue;
        }

        if(wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            _stprintf_s(tszPathTemp, MAX_PATH, _T("%s\\%s"),Path,wfd.cFileName);
            log(_T("dir: %s"), tszPathTemp);
            nd->subnodes.push_back(new node());
            ndparent = nd;
            nd = nd->subnodes[nd->subnodes.size()-1];
            nd->val.push_back(wstring(wfd.cFileName));
            nd->parent = ndparent;
            SearchFile(tszPathTemp, nd);

        }
        else
        {
            _stprintf_s(tszPathTemp, MAX_PATH, _T("%s\\%s"),Path, wfd.cFileName);
            log(_T("dir: %s, filename:%s"), tszPathTemp, wfd.cFileName);

            nd->val.push_back(wstring(wfd.cFileName));
        }

    }while(FindNextFile(hFind,&wfd));

    FindClose(hFind);
}

int main()
{
    vector<wstring> file;
    nd = new node();
    nd->parent = ndparent;
    SearchFile(_T("Y:"), nd);
    while(nd->parent != NULL)
    {
        nd = nd->parent;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can do it but it's not practical, it can take a very long time if there are too many files and sub directories. The way File Explorer does it is it goes through files and the sub directories on first level only. It checks the sub directories on first level to see if they have children. The sub directories on first level are marked them as expandable or non-expandable.

Comment: Yes, you can. What's keeping you from just doing it? Do note that using a vector of string **pointers** pretty much defies the purpose the C++' automatic memory management.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive function to find all files and sub folders, then put them in one array:

```
void files_and_folders(vector<wstring> &sa, wstring dir)
{
    if (!dir.size()) return;
    if (dir[dir.size() - 1] != L'\\') dir += L"\\";

    WIN32_FIND_DATA find = { 0 };
    wstring wildcard = dir + L"*";
    HANDLE hfind = FindFirstFile(wildcard.c_str(), &find);
    if (hfind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return;

    do
    {
        if (wcscmp(find.cFileName, L".") == 0 || wcscmp(find.cFileName, L"..") == 0)
            continue;
        wstring path = dir + find.cFileName;
        sa.push_back(path);

        if (find.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            files_and_folders(sa, path);

    } while (FindNextFile(hfind, &find));

    FindClose(hfind);
}

int wmain()
{
    vector<wstring> sa;
    files_and_folders(sa, L"c:\\program files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox");
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)sa.size(); i++)
        wcout << sa[i] << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The result will look like this:

```
c:\program files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\AccessibleMarshal.dll
c:\program files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\application.ini
c:\program files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\breakpadinjector.dll
c:\program files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser
c:\program files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\blocklist.xml
c:\program files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\chrome.manifest
...
```

You would want to sort the result. I also have some sort functions for these, I have to convert them from MFC.

Comment: Your code `vector<wstring> sa` was a vector of string  but I need a tree data structure. So that does not meet my needs. But thanks anyway.